# What does cd // means (change directory to //)

Tags: linux, root, cd, pwd

I'm still a Linux newbie and I'm wondering: What is the Linux directory // ?

I can change dir (cd) to the root dir using cd /

```
~> cd /
/>
```

Using pwd (print name of working directory) tells me I'm in root (/)

```
/> pwd
/
```

Using ls (list directory contents) I see the following (using Raspbian Jessie)

```
/> ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  include  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  share  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

By mistake I changed dir to // and found that it was valid:

```
~> cd //
//>
```

Also using pwd tells me I'm in a directory called // :

```
//> pwd
//
```

But using ls I see the that I'm probably still in 'something' looking like root.

```
//> ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  include  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  share  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

... but telling me it's called // (rootroot ;-)

So what is directory // ?

Comment: It's the same as `/`, but I too wonder why `cd //` sets the current directory to `//`

Comment: Apparently, every two `/` are stripped: `cd ///` goes to `/` and `cd ////` to `//`.

Comment: Perfectly covered in [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12283/40596), which was migrated from [so].

Comment: Please forgive me for asking this kind of question here. I'm a newbie not only using Linux but also in understanding how to use the different Stack Exchange communities. I try to learn - but slowly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Linux (and most other platforms), multiple slashes in a path are interpreted the same as a single slash. However, the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) states that:

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

// may be reserved for a special purpose (e.g: accessing a network drive in Cygwin). However, if you check ls in / and // on Linux you should see the same content.